# cloudwatch lambda logs not showing nested object content

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

When I try to see the log of the nested object, it shows it as [object] instead of showing the actual object.
Before i Console.log the object it looks fine, only show like this in the log itself.

The output looks like this:

```
 { url: 'https://api.11111.co.il/v1/items/11111',
     method: 'put',
     internal_data:
      { content_type: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        content_format: 'string' },
     data:
      { token:
         'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        item: [Object] } } }
```

[log image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9vse.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using NodeJs, you should log objects as

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(objectToPrint))
```

Other languages also have different mechanisms to convert complex JSON objects to string.